# javascript = vs == with if and else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, boolean

I have a variable `var stIm = '';` and I am trying to put it into an if and else statement.

When I have

`if (stIm = ''){}else{}`
it only runs the if part

`if (stIm == ''){}else{}`
it only runs the else part

Does anyone knows how to fix this?
Does `===` work?

Comment: You are a bit confused - `=` is not for comparison, it is an assignment operator. You probably should be asking `==` vs `===` in if statements - there is plenty of that on google

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first

```js
var stIm = '';

if (stIm = '') { // assignment with a falsy value
    console.log('if');
} else {
    console.log('else');
}
```

assigns a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, (like `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `false`, empty string `''`) and goes to the `else` part.

But the second works.

```js
var stIm = '';

if (stIm == '') {
    console.log('if');
} else {
    console.log('else');
}
```

But take better a [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) which does not coerces the values and checks the left and right operand first by type and then by value.

Comment: I would think that if the OP doesn't know the difference between `=` and `==`, then they likely don't know what you mean by "falsy".

Answer (score 0):

First if **if (stIm  = ''){ console.log('yes'); }else{console.log('no');}** tell the "compiler", variable stIm take the '' (empty string value), if(empty string) is false, the console will print "no" and will execute the else statement.

The second if, trying to compare 2 empty strings and this will return true. "Yes" will be displayed in the console.

The `===` equals will return the same true because will compare 2 empty strings.

Answer (score -1):

You need to perform a deep equality check with === . == only compares the value. So 2 == "2" is true. However, 2 === "2" is false. === compares both value AND type.

So you could write:

```js
if(stIm === ""){
return stuff
}
return otherStuff
```

You don't need else if you write "return" in your if statement. A quicker way would be to use a ternary condition:

```js
stIm === "" ? stuff : otherStuff
```

Comment: `2 = "2"` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yeah, I typed too fast and forgot an "=". I meant 2=="2" is true.